# What’s the purpose put a .so file before execution file?

Tags: linux, bash, yocto

I saw a execution method today.

```
/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so ./foo
```

I know when putting a bash variable before execution command means to set that environment variable before execute command.

But now, it is a share lib, what’s the purpose and function to put there?

Comment: Where did you see that?

Comment: Yocto Environment.

Comment: That's not actually a library; it's the dynamic linker. See https://linux.die.net/man/8/ld-linux. This won't work for an *arbitrary* `.so` file.

Comment: https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/manpages/ld-linux.so.8.en.html

Comment: Only linker can do this way?

Comment: In this specific case, `/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so` is an executable command (not true of all `.so` files). Any such executable command can work that way. It doesn't have to be a linker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dynamic linker `/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so` is special in that it can be run as an executable *or* linked to another executable to use as a library itself. This isn't something you can do with an arbitrary `.so` file, though.

Either way, its purpose is to allow `./foo` to load other shared libraries at run time. For more information, see [its manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ld-linux).